# Two tunings included with Scala: "Tau-On-Side Opposite" and "Upside Down Wedding Cake"

Tags: tuning, software, microtonality

Scala comes with a [very large collection of tunings](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/docs/scalesdir.txt). Many of these are mysterious to me. Specifically, I'm seeking information about these two:

```
pyramid_down.scl               12  Upside-Down Wedding Cake (divorce cake) 
t-side2.scl                    12  Tau-on-Side opposite
```

I'll take anything I can get at this point -- historical information about who made them and why, technical / mathematical information about how they're constructed, examples of their use in music etc.

Incidentally, I have no reason to believe these are related, they just stood out to me when I was exploring the collection. I'm currently using them both in a piece of music so I'd like to be able to say something about them when asked (or even when nobody asks).

Comment: You probably know that doing SHOW SCALE with different SET ATTRIBUTES values gives you some clues to the mathematics involved. But although I've used a number of the tunings, only occasionally could I find out who had created them or how or why. The Tunings mailing-list closed, then the Yahoo Group, and now I think there is only Facebook, which has four or more groups, each specializing in some aspect of microtonal music. How keen are you to pursue it? I've got a few links and also some names of people who might be able to help.

Comment: As for examples of their use, I've used Graham Breed's scale of 12 notes to a schismatic fourth and a 19-note scale from Thorvald Kornerup's Golden meantone.
I've got some big 'band' and 'orchestral' pieces using 06-41 Hexatonic scale in 41-tet and 07-37 Miller's Porcupine-7 but not the scales you are interested in. Neil Haverstick has pieces of his on his site, mostly using 19 and 34-note E.T., played on specially-fretted guitars. I would guess that a tuning like a wedding cake would have narrow intervals at the top and wide at the base, so divorce cakes would be the opposite. Tau? No idea!

Comment: Thanks for the insight -- at least I'm not missing something obvious... I'll take any leads you have (regarding these tunings or sources of information in general). I'm more ear-led these days so I'm happy to have found sounds I enjoy but I'd like to at least be able to give credit where it's due.

Comment: If you're still interested, I had a couple of emails with some contact details. I'll post them here in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Tunings and creation dates from [ScalaVista Online Scale Archive](https://scalavista.zentral.zone/)

**Pyramid / Wedding Cake**

```
Created: February 19, 1996

9/8, 75/64, 5/4, 4/3, 45/32, 3/2, 25/16, 5/3, 27/16, 16/9, 15/8, 2/1
```

**Pyramid down / Upside-down Wedding Cake / Divorce Cake**

```
Created: February 19, 1996

16/15, 9/8, 6/5, 32/25, 4/3, 3/2, 8/5, 27/16, 16/9, 9/5, 48/25, 2/1
```

**Tau-on-side**

```
Created: February 2, 2010

25/24, 16/15, 9/8, 5/4, 4/3, 45/32, 3/2, 25/16, 8/5, 5/3, 15/8, 2/1
```

**Tau-on-side opposite**

```
Created: March 24, 2003

9/8, 75/64, 6/5, 5/4, 4/3, 45/32, 3/2, 5/3, 225/128, 9/5, 15/8, 2/1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Groups! is shutting down permanently on December 15, 2020, meaning that even email functionality will be broken.

At this point, virtually all of the online microtonal/xenharmonic presence is at Facebook's "Xenharmonic Alliance," "Xenharmonic Alliance - Mathematical Theory", and "Microtonal Music and Tuning Theory" groups. You are all encouraged to join those!

The messages from this group have all been archived. The archive is at:
https://yahootuninggroupsultimatebackup.github.io/

You can also always get the Xenharmonic Wiki at:
https://en.xen.wiki/w/Main_Page

Thanks and I'll see you all there!

---

There's also a group on MeWe (Dr. Oz posts there, but he's not on Facebook).
https://mewe.com/group/5c9c1bc3d71e3023f90fe123

....and an email list run by Aaron Krister Johnson at tuning-discuss@untwelve.org. You should be able to sign up here:
http://lists.untwelve.org/listinfo.cgi/tuning-discuss-untwelve.org

There's also a (quiet) Slack, if you're interested in more real-time interactions. Let me know if you're interested.

---

Jake Freivald

Comment: This seems like a good Q/A in its own right. ...and possible more likely to be found.

Comment: @Aaron Did you see my *message* above? My answer just consists of a couple of emails from various members of the late-lamented Tunings Group, who sent an email round saying where to find what's left of it. Do you mean I should ask eg 'Where to find tunings info?' then answer it with the info in their emails? I guess I could, if that's what you meant. Btw, the archived messages are useful, and *searchable*. Well done finding Wedding Cake etc. Remiss of me not to have checked the  ScalaVista Online Scale Archive back in May when the OP asked the question. Do you dip a toe in other tunings?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was suggesting you post a question like "Where to find tunings info?" I'm often wrong about these things, but my sense is it might prove useful to a fair number of people. As far as alternative tunings -- not as a performer (or, not on purpose as a performer), but academically it's an area of curiosity if not a great deal of knowledge.

Comment: @Aaron Ok I'll do that. Thanks. My math(s) isn't good enough to follow some of the discussions the experts have, but there are certainly some beautiful tunings.

Comment: Thanks very much for these links, and to Aaron for the info from the Archive; I appreciate both. I'm not on any of the platforms you mention but maybe that should change. Looks like Old Brixtonian's question will be a good lightning rod for collecting links: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/106882/where-to-find-information-about-tunings.